# Excel - IF one cell is blank then show blank, if not then formula unless

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet where I am inputing an arrival date (B3), An approval Date (K3) and showing how many days that I have left until the due date (in this cell).

I have used this formula to calculate this....

```
=IF(B3="","",(B3+21))
```

but would also like the cell to also show blank when the approval date(k3) is populated.

[image]

THanks,

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
=IF(K3<>"","",IF(B3="","",(B3+21)))
```